# Why does acts_as_paranoid break my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session-variables, acts-as-paranoid

I recently added the **"paranoid"** gem to the `User model` of my project. This model also uses `"has_secure_password"`; which works perfectly until I place `"acts_as_paranoid"` at the top of my `User model`. Now all I'm getting the following argument error:

```
Started GET "/users/8/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-16 20:57:48 -0400
Processing by UsersController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"8"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
  app/models/user.rb:19:in `hash'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:25:in `current_user'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:11:in `signed_in?'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:33:in `signed_in_user'
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    before_create :create_remember_token

    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
    validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => ['active', 'inactive']
    has_secure_password


    def User.new_remember_token
        SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

    def User.hash(token)
        Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
    end

private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = User.hash(User.new_remember_token)
    end

end
```

And here is my session helper:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.hash(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end


  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user     
  end

   def current_user
    remember_token = User.hash(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
  end

   def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end

  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url if request.get?
  end

end
```

Comment: `hash` is a system method. Choose another name for your digest generating method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.hash` [by convention of its parent class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-hash) takes no arguments and should return a `Fixnum`.

It is used for object comparison by other classes throughout the Ruby language, for example when looking up the value of a key in a `Hash`. If `a.eql?(b)`, then `a.hash == b.hash` must be true as well.

The best way to fix the issue is to rename your `hash` method to something else, not to get in the way of the Ruby conventions.